# React FusionCharts Dynamic Json

Tags: reactjs, fusioncharts

I am using FusionCharts and I am trying to pass a Json variable to the chart.

```
 var q = {
   "data": understandingPercentageJson
  };

  var y = {
   "category": daysJson
  };

  chartConfigs2 = {
  type: 'msline',
  renderAt: 'chart-container',
  width: '700',
  height: '400',
  dataFormat: 'json',
  dataSource: {
    "chart": {
      "theme": "fusion",
      "caption": "understanding",
      "subCaption": "This is a sub-caption",
      "xAxisName": "days"
    },
    "categories": [{
      y
    }], 
    "dataset": [{
        "seriesname":"Understanding of topic",
        q
      },
      {
        "seriesname": "Los Angeles Topanga",
        "data": [{
            "value": "20"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
  };
```

Where  'daysJson' is in json. A console.log shows [{"label":"25-01-2019"}]
And 'understandingPercentageJson' using console.log displays [{"value":40}]

How I get 'understandingPercentageJson':

```
    var understandingPercentage = [];
    var keyValuePair = {
       "value": 40.toString()
      };
   understandingPercentage.push(keyValuePair);
   var understandingPercentageJson = 
   JSON.stringify(understandingPercentage);
```

The problem is when I use these variables, the chart give me 'Understanding of topic, **undefined**'. When I use the same values hard coded (values copy paste from console), it works perfectly. I am confused as to why when using the variables it give me an undefined message

Updated question

Comment: Try to replace JSON string with javascript object in this, `"data": understandingPercentage`

Comment: @SelvaTS I tried and it gave me a 'no data to display' error on the chart. I believe its because im not creating the "categories" object

Comment: Have you not populated `"category": daysJson` object? If it doesnt has any value, pass empty string.

Comment: @SelvaTS Updated question. Let me know what you think. They do have data as the console.log outputs data I have listed above

Comment: It seems still the `daysJson` not populated.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone I managed to fix the issue. You don't need to Json.stringify. The array understandingPercentage is what you need to put into the chartconfig